Deploy AlienVault USM from Azure Marketplace using Terraform
Has anyone had any success/experience deploying the AlienVault USM Linux VM from the Azure Marketplace using Terraform?
I have the following main.tf module:
# VM depends on NIC
# Create network interface first
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines

  name                = each.value.nic_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = each.value.ip_configuration.name
    subnet_id                     = each.value.ip_configuration.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.ip_configuration.private_ip_address_allocation
    private_ip_address            = each.value.ip_configuration.private_ip_address
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines

  name                            = each.value.name
  computer_name                   = each.value.computer_name
  location                        = var.location
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  size                            = var.vm_size
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id]
  availability_set_id             = var.availability_set_name != "" ? azurerm_availability_set.avset[0].id : null
  admin_username                  = var.admin_username
  admin_password                  = var.admin_password
  disable_password_authentication = false


  dynamic "os_disk" {
    for_each = {
      for index, os_disk in each.value.os_disk : os_disk.name => os_disk
    }
    content {
      name                 = os_disk.value.name
      caching              = os_disk.value.caching
      storage_account_type = os_disk.value.storage_account_type
      disk_size_gb         = os_disk.value.disk_size_gb
    }
  }

  dynamic "source_image_reference" {
    for_each = {
      for index, source_image_reference in each.value.source_image_reference : source_image_reference.publisher => source_image_reference
    }
    content {
      publisher = source_image_reference.value.publisher
      offer     = source_image_reference.value.offer
      sku       = source_image_reference.value.sku
      version   = source_image_reference.value.version
    }
  }
}

# Optional availability set
resource "azurerm_availability_set" "avset" {
  count                       = var.availability_set_name != "" ? 1 : 0
  name                        = var.availability_set_name
  location                    = var.location
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group_name
  managed                     = true
  platform_fault_domain_count = 2 # For managed disks this can only be in the range of 1-2
}

# Data disks
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "disk" {
  for_each = {
    for index, data_disk in var.data_disks : data_disk.name => data_disk
  }

  name                 = each.value.name
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  create_option        = "Empty"
  storage_account_type = each.value.storage_account_type
  disk_size_gb         = each.value.disk_size_gb
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "data_disk_attach" {
  for_each = {
    for index, data_disk in var.data_disks : data_disk.name => data_disk
  }

  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.disk[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = values(azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm)[0].id
  lun                = each.value.lun
  caching            = each.value.caching
}

And I'm passing in the from the calling/child module:
locals {
  primary_location = "UK South"
  environment      = "dev"
  rg_name          = "rg-temp"
}

module "linux_vm" {
  source = "../"

  location              = local.primary_location
  resource_group_name   = local.rg_name
  vm_size               = "Standard_B2ms"
  admin_username        = "xadmin " # Default user to create?
  admin_password        = "TerraPass11."
  availability_set_name = ""
  tags                  = {}

  virtual_machines = {
    "usm-001" = {
      name          = "usm-001"
      computer_name = "usm-001"
      os_disk = [
        {
          name                 = "usm-001-osdisk-001"
          caching              = "None"
          storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
          disk_size_gb         = 128
          create_option        = "FromImage"
        }
      ]

      source_image_reference = [
        {
          publisher = "alienvault"
          offer     = "unified-security-management-anywhere"
          sku       = "unified-security-management-anywhere"
          version   = "latest"
        }
      ]

      nic_name = "nic-dev-usm-001"
      ip_configuration = {
        name                          = "usm-001"
        subnet_id                     = "/subscriptions/e286703f-8ba4-4a0d-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/shared-networks/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/shared-vnet-10/subnets/1-24"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
        private_ip_address            = "10.10.1.20"
      }
    }
  }

  data_disks = [
    {
      name                 = "data-disk-001-usm-001"
      caching              = "None"
      create_option        = "Empty"
      storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
      disk_size_gb         = 50
      lun                  = 1
    }
  ]
}

But it's complaining about something to do with the storage? (I think it's specifically unhappy about dataDisks?).
│ Error: creating Linux Virtual Machine (Subscription: "e286703f-8ba4-4a0d-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "rg-temp"
│ Virtual Machine Name: "usm-001"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: InvalidParameter: StorageProfile.dataDisks.lun does not have required value(s) for image specified in storage profile.
│
│   with module.linux_vm.azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm["usm-001"],
│   on ../main.tf line 18, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm":
│   18: resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {

Running this for/against a standard Ubuntu Marketplace server image selection works correctly, I end up with a Linux VM with x1 OS disk and x1 attached empty data disk.
The marketplace AlienVault image on Azure isn't really giving much info. I tried running the Azure deployment wizard in the UI to see what kind of ARM template it creates, and I'm seeing this as part of the overall template:
"dataDisks1": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "lun": 0,
                    "createOption": "fromImage",
                    "deleteOption": "Detach",
                    "caching": "None",
                    "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
                    "id": null,
                    "name": null,
                    "storageAccountType": null,
                    "diskSizeGB": null,
                    "tier": null,
                    "diskEncryptionSet": null
                }
            ]
        },

Why it would need to create an empty disk using FromImage?
My understanding is that if you set a Terrafrom Azure data disk create_option to FromImage then you have to supply the image ID?.....but I don't see any mention of this anywhere in the whole ARM template or how to obtain this ID (is it possible to reference it from the source_image_reference sub-block in the main vm block?).
The AlienVault website is sadly void of any Terraform documentation of any kind that I can see.
Has anyone had an experience with this kind of thing before?
Appreciate any guidance anyone might have.
Thanks.

Try to remove data disk configuration form this script as this info will be fetched directly from the image while creation @scott

Hey @VinayB. Yeah, I tried removing the datadisk completely. It gives the same error. The weird thing is, if I deploy this using click ops and look into the config behind it, the empty datadisk shows it was created using 'ImageFrom' and then 'image_reference_id' that points to the full URL of the AlienWare image (which I can understand for the OS disk, but not a data disk). I cannot figure out how/why the vendor have setup the disks in such an awkward way. Am wondering if the vendor image was created on the older 'azurerm_windows_virtual_machine' before they split to windows and linux?

For info. We ended up doing this using resource type 'azurerm_virtual_machine'. I guess that's what the vendor used when they made the marketplace image/appliance.

can you please share the solution so that it will be help for the community if someone came across the similar issue @Scott


Deploy AlienVault USM from Azure Marketplace using Terraform

Hello Scott, seems like you already found a solution to your problem, I am just posting it here for ease of other folks who are facing similar issue on SO. Please feel free to add any points / your inputs to this if required.
What you mentioned in the comment is on track because if a vendor publishes a Marketplace image, they may specify certain plans that need to be associated with that image when they deployed it which in general happens in azurerm_virtual_machine& not included in your azurerm_linux_virtual_machine. Sometimes OS specifications can also be the issue for these cases.
I tried  a demo terraform code as per suggestion such that it can be helpful for the community people who might try to provision the same image VM.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "usm-001"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_B2ms"

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "usm-001-osdisk-001"
    caching           = "None"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "usm-001"
    admin_username = "xadmin"
    admin_password = "TerraPass11." 

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "alienvault"
    offer     = "unified-security-management-anywhere"
    sku       = "unified-security-management-anywhere"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  
   plan {
    name      = "unified-security-management-anywhere"
    product   = "unified-security-management-anywhere"
    publisher = "alienvault"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "data_disk" {
  name                 = "data-disk-001"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  create_option        = "Empty"
  storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  disk_size_gb         = 50

  depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_machine.vm ]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "data_disk_attach" {
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.data_disk.id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  lun                = 1  # Logical Unit Number for the data disk
  caching            = "None"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_virtual_machine.vm, azurerm_managed_disk.data_disk ]
}

Deployment:



Refer:
azurerm_virtual_machine | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
